# System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

В общем, почему-то при выполнении Publish, как Standalone Win x64 приложение, вылетает ошибка Sql client is not supported on this platform, хотя, если запускать из под VS, то все нормально.

.Net Core стоит 2.2 версии с последними доступными версиями либ для работы с Sql Server.

В чем может быть проблема?

Сначала грешил на то, что  миграции пытаюсь выполнить в Startup.cs, но после выпиливания начал валиться с такой же ошибкой при попытке вычитать данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто пописал ручками в файл-проекта:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> --Вот это
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <UserSecretsId>ed6862ca-e455-4714-9552-bff6407b2370</UserSecretsId>   </PropertyGroup>
```

После этого все стало работать.